# DateTime.AddDays vs Calendar.AddDays

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, calendar, globalization

What is the difference between `DateTime.AddDays` and `Calendar.AddDays`?
Is `DateTime` type calendar independent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DateTime.AddDays just converts days to ticks and adds this number of ticks to the date time. The default implementation of Calendar.AddDays does exactly the same. However, since it is a virtual method it can be implemented in specific calendar in a more complicated way, e.g. something like here: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic/

Answer (score 7):

I believe that `DateTime` is hard-coded to use the Gregorian calendar, effectively.

For example, if you look at [`DateTime.DaysInMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx) it assumes there are 12 months, whereas the [`HebrewCalendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.hebrewcalendar.aspx) supports 13.

EDIT: There are some aspects of `DateTime` which *do* accommodate other calendars, such as [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d7b9xsh.aspx). However, I believe it just converts it to a Gregorian calendar:

```
Calendar calendar = new HebrewCalendar();
DateTime dt = new DateTime(5901, 13, 1, 0, 0, 0, calendar); // Uses month 13!
Console.WriteLine(dt.Year); // 2141
Console.WriteLine(dt.Month); // 9
```

Comment: Thanks. Reflector shows that they use calendar.ToDateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, 0).Ticks inside constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the `Calendar.AddDays` method returns a `DateTime` object and calls it's function.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is extremely easy to answer.  There is no difference between the two functions.

[Calendar.AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.adddays.aspx) is also a DateTime

DateTime does not extend that particular functionality the only thing it uses is UTC and Local time.  One should also suggest that a Calendar is NOT a DateTime object, it might not behave the same, **and does not appear to provide a method to get the current system time.**

*Edit - I originally thought you were talking about the Web Control, this appears to be a globalization, to allow you to display the current date and time for a given user base do their declared operating system's settings.*