# DateTime.AddDays(7) vs Calendar.AddWeeks(1)

Tags: .net, datetime, calendar, globalization

Can both methods deliver different results under certain circumstances? Same question for negative values...

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793788/datetime-adddays-vs-calendar-adddays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from Reflector:

```
public DateTime AddDays(double value)
{
    return this.Add(value, 86400000);
}

public virtual DateTime AddWeeks(DateTime time, int weeks)
{
    return this.AddDays(time, weeks * 7);
}
```

Note, however, that AddWeeks is defined as `virtual`.

Answer (score 2):

They always do the same thing.  AddMonth and AddYears will vary but a week is always 7 days